# Windows Server 2012 R2 Virtual Switch

Tags: sql-server, iis, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

We have an Dell R510 that has Windows Server 2012 R2 Core installed. We are having a problem where the guest VMs are losing their network connections but will come back after a couple of minutes.

The server was originally using BroadCom NetXtreme NIC but we replaced it with a Intel NIC. The problem persists randomly even in the middle of the night when there is no traffic it will drop.

Any ideas of what may be happening or where we could should be looking?

Comment: Does the host lose connection on that link as well, same time the VM does ? What model on Intel NIC do you have now ? Did you test with VMQ disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several points that could be causing issues.

I would start by checking for updated drivers from Intel. If that doesn't fix it, try another NIC. If that doesn't work, try another switch (the issue could be outside of the server. Is this the only system that you are seeing the issue on?).

If none of that works, it is possible that the virual switch service is resetting (for whatever reason). Any errors in events?

Comment: We tried all of the above. Latest drivers from Intel. It originally had a BroadCom NIC that had the problem replaced it with Intel NIC and still has problem. Tried different switch. We only see this problem on our Hyper-V server. We looked in event logs on the Core box and did not see any errors. Question is teaming NIC cards required? Would that help this sort of problem?

Comment: Do you have multiple network connections to the same network connected to the same server? If so, would you be able to either team them or limit it to 1 connection for a while to test?

If you are using dns to access the server, having multiple IP addresses on the network for one server could cause weird issues.

Comment: We have a 4 port NIC. One port is reserved for the management network and One port is setup for the virtual switch there are 3 servers on the virtual switch all with static IP addresses.